# VS2010 Just-InTime Debugger

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

again, guys,

Just a quick question with regard to the JIT debugger. I have a Windows Form that allows you to control an associated service through buttons. The buttons work, I can fully control the service and no crashes occur. However, whenever I stop the service, I get the following message:

```
An unhandled exception"'System.ObjectDisposedException') occurred in Proxy_Service_3_5.exe
```

After which, the application continues happily. I can restart the service through the form again, with no issue, and then stop it, at which point I get the JIT call again. Has anyone else experienced this? I've included the button's code below, let me know if anything else is needed.

```
private void btnStopService_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (GetServiceStatus(ServiceName) == "STOPPED")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Service is not running");
        }
        else
        {
            try{
                myService.Stop();
                tbServiceStatus.Text = GetServiceStatus(ServiceName);
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Cheers.

Comment: You need to debug this.  Starting from the stack trace in the exception.